# Python and GTK+: How to create garbage collector friendly objects?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, gtk, pygtk

I started writing a small application in Python with GTK+ as my widget toolkit. Recently I decided to do some memory optimization and noticed that a most of PyGTK objects I create never gets released by garbage collector. This number keeps growing even if I open a window and properly destroy it afterward.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to create and handle GTK+ objects from Python. Am not using Glade or anything like that.

Also I noticed that creating window like this:

```
class SomeWindow:
   def __init__(self):
      self.window = gtk.Window(type=gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
```

Instead of:

```
class SomeWindow(gtk.Window):
   def __init__(self):
      super(SomeWindow, self).__init__(type=gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
```

Gives 2+ objects less in GC list.

Any advices you can give me?

Comment: Unless it's a severe bug, they *will* be collected - sooner or later. Cyclic references make instanct reclaiming impossible (or, at least, impractical), leading to the effect you see, but they are almost unavoidable in GUI toolkits.

Comment: @delnan thanks for answering, will this change when GTK+ for python is GI based?

Comment: What do you mean with "the GC list"? You mean the number you get with gc.collect(); print len(gc.garbage()) is increasing?

Comment: @maxy No, am tracking len(gc.get_objects()) and that is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call .destroy()?

According to the [gtk.Widget.destroy](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--destroy) docu GTK maintains a list of toplevel windows that will keep a reference alive.

And in case you use any Python destructors, they can also prevent cyclic references from being freed.

Comment: If I call destroy on top level widgets I do free up more objects but still not the same number of created ones. For example, creating a window adds 50 or so objects to GC list of tracked objects. Destroying that window I free up 20 or something.